# Connection refreshing in Excel 2010 but not 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013, vba

So here is my subroutine in Excel:

```
Sub refreshAll()    
    Dim con As String
    Dim percent As String
    Dim cLen As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim pInt As Double

    cLen = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.count
    total = cLen - 1        
    For i = 0 To total
        con = "Connection" & i
        pInt = i / cLen
        percent = FormatPercent(pInt, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(con).Refresh
        Application.StatusBar = "Updated " & i & " of " & cLen & " | " & percent & " Complete"
    Next i
    Application.StatusBar = "Update Finished"        
End Sub
```

In Excel 2010, this works perfectly, but in Excel 2013 all it does is zip through all the connections without actually refreshing them.  The connections are background refresh disabled, I have verified that 2010 does in fact work, but 2013 does not.  Does anyone know if the ActiveWorkbook.Connections(x).Refresh doesn't work in 2013?  Maybe there a setting I'm probably missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this MSDN nugget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197503.aspx), try this longshot:

```
ActiveWookbook.Connections(con).Refresh(False)
```

According to the linked article, `False` should wait until after the data is fetched. However, as I said, this might be a longshot.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error: "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"